# GSheet wrap strategy in pygsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

In the Pygsheet reference doc [here](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cell.html?highlight=wrap_strategy#cell) it shows a wrap_strategy property.

```
wrap_strategy
How to wrap text in this cell. Possible wrap strategies: ‘OVERFLOW_CELL’, ‘LEGACY_WRAP’, ‘CLIP’, ‘WRAP’. Reference: api docs
```

But in actual code if I were to `cell.wrap_strategy = 'WRAP'` I get an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Actual code snippet:

```
for cell in wsheet.range("L3:L20").pop():
    cell.wrap_strategy('WRAP')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the wrap strategy using pygsheets.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw [the script of `wrap_strategy` of pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/blob/staging/pygsheets/cell.py#L175), it seems that this is the Class Cell and in this case, I think that in the case of `for cell in wsheet.range("L3:L20").pop():`, you can use `cell.wrap_strategy = 'WRAP'`. (In this case, it sets to "L20".)

From this, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
for cell in wsheet.range("L3:L20").pop():
    cell.wrap_strategy = "WRAP"
```

or, as other direction, how about using `get_values` as follows?

```
for cell in wsheet.get_values("L3", "L20", returnas="range")._data.pop():
    cell.wrap_strategy = "WRAP"
```

#### Note:

- If above modification was not the direct solution of your issue, can you provide your whole script without your personal information? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [wrap_strategy](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cell.html?highlight=wrap_strategy#pygsheets.Cell.wrap_strategy)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> I was expecting it to wrap L3 to L20. But it seems only L20 is being read in this for loop. Would you know how to make it so?

When I saw your script in your question, you wanted to use the last element of `wsheet.range("L3:L20")` because of `pop()`. So I followed to it. From your replying, when you want to set the wap strategy for "L3:L20" by modifying your script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample 1:

```
for cell in wsheet.range("L3:L20"):
    cell[0].wrap_strategy = "WRAP"
```

#### Sample 2:

```
for cell in wsheet.get_values("L3", "L20", returnas="range")._data:
    cell[0].wrap_strategy = "WRAP"
```

Comment: I was expecting it to wrap L3 to L20. But it seems only L20 is being read in this for loop. Would you know how to make it so?

Comment: @Luigi Mackenzie C. Brito Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your replying, I added one more sample. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: no need to apologize. You are amazing I got it now. I forgot why I popped it but I was intending it to run on all cell based on range

Comment: @Luigi Mackenzie C. Brito Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.